# Load JSON file from pc folder on codepen project

Tags: jquery, json, file, codepen

So I got a JSON file made by my self on a pc folder and I would like to load it into a CodePen project.
Since I don't have the typical url taken from the web, how can I load it on that CodePen project?
I saw similar questions on StackOverflow but I can't find a good answer for my case.
I don't even know if it is possible to do this thing but I try to ask it here.
Thank you all!

Comment: You cant load it directly into CodePen. But you can copy/paste the content of the file into a variable and point the code to read this variable.

Comment: Read https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/asset-hosting/

Comment: I see that's a paid feature, but it should give you an idea. There are free alternatives to copy and paste a text file, for example making a gist on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant load it directly into CodePen. But you can copy/paste the content of the file into a variable and point the code to read this variable.